# Video de fondo en proyecto Node.js desplegado en cPanel no se muestra correctamente en diferentes navegadores y dispositivos

Tags: nodejs, express, cpanel

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto web usando Node.js y Express, desplegado a través de cPanel. Estoy enfrentando un problema específico donde un video de fondo no se muestra correctamente en diferentes navegadores y dispositivos.

He configurado una sección en mi página HTML para mostrar un video de fondo. Sin embargo, el video no se muestra en algunos dispositivos y navegadores, mientras que en otros se visualiza correctamente. No hay errores consistentes en la consola que indiquen un problema claro.

URL: https://livegood-pay.network/

```
<div class="video-background">
    <video autoplay loop muted playsinline>
        <source src="/videos/fondo-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Tu navegador no soporta videos HTML5.
    </video>
    <div class="video-overlay"></div>
</div>
```

---

```
/*VIDEO DE FONDO */

.hero {
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.video-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
}


.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Capa oscura con 70% de transparencia */
    z-index: 0; /* Asegúrate de que está entre el video y el contenido */
}

.video-background video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover; /* Asegura que el video cubra toda el área sin distorsionarse */
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    /* Estilos adicionales para centrar y estilizar el contenido */
}
```

---

Intentos de Solución:

- Verificado que las rutas a los archivos de video son correctas.
- Asegurado que el servidor de Express sirva correctamente los archivos estáticos desde la carpeta public.
- Probado con diferentes formatos de video (mp4, webm).

¿Qué podría estar causando este comportamiento inconsistente en la visualización del video? ¿Hay algún paso adicional que debería considerar para asegurar la compatibilidad en diferentes navegadores y dispositivos?